# how to use map(key, value) in kivy (python)?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

How to fill up the label and TextInput dynamically?  Fetching should be automatically fill in the label and TextInput.

```
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 50, 50, 50, 50
            orientation: 'horizontal'

            BoxLayout:
                spacing: 50
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_x: 1
                Label:
                    text: 'a'
                Label:
                    text: 'b'
                Label:
                    text: 'c'

            BoxLayout:
                spacing: 50
                orientation: 'vertical'
                TextInput:
                    text: 'Goc'
                TextInput:
                    text: 'Coc'
                TextInput:
                    text: 'Dow'
```

Comment: Did you have a look at RecycleView?

Comment: Yes dear @Tshirtman, but how to fetch data in label and TextInput? May be some loop and small function should be there. By the way, I have tried RecycleView , it didn't came for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should give an id: to each widget 
(like:

```
TextInput:
    id: ti1
TextInput:
    id: ti2
```

and so on for all widgets of your interest)

(see Kivy official site) and fill them from wherever you want accessing the 'text' property of the widget just like this:
    self.ids.ti1.text='jkhgk....'
where self is your  widget:

```
class Test(SomeClass):
    def settext(self):
       self.ids.ti1.text='Cog' or whatever...
```

and bind this settext func by any way (in kv file or in py file) to your control's on_press, on_check and so on